# R smartbind produces extra column

Tags: r, merge, rbind, merging-data

Adding rows to dataframe is easy with `rbind` but i find that `smartbind` is often better at handling exceptions such as dataframes with different columnnames and so on.

However Iteratively adding rows in `smartbind` produces an additional row in some instances:

```
library(gtools)
alldf <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(x=i)
  alldf<- smartbind(df,alldf)
}
```

`smartbind` :

```
> alldf
    x
1   3
2:1 2
2:2 1
2:3 1
```

`rbind`  :

```
> alldf
  x
1 3
2 2
3 1
```

I don't have a clue why `smartbind` does this, i've tried fiddling with removal of rownames `rownames(alldf) <- NULL`, but it doesn't seem to change this. I can use `rbind` instead for now, or i could inititalize the `alldf` on the first loop, but it seems like a hassle. Plus, I sometimes prefer to use `smartbind` so i would like to correct this.

Thanks for Reading

Comment: did you try `rownames(alldf) <- NULL` ?

Comment: yeb - same result

Comment: I am no expert on this package or function but if you add the argument `verbose = TRUE` in `smartbind` maybe you will see what's happening